# .net mvc Partial View broken when using 5-Tuple

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, tuples

Don't know, if it's VS (2019 16.8.2) bug, or I'm doing something wrong, but my partial view is broken, when I add 5th item to Model Tuple. 4-Tuple is OK, 5-Tuple is shown as 1-Tuple, 6-Tuple as 2-Tuple etc...

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried closing view, rebuilding, clean+rebuild, restarting VS, and ofcourse googling.

Comment: So this is likely a bug or a limitation with the Roslyn version it uses. What you need to do is, ***not*** paste images of errors or at least paste the actual error so other people can find this error when searching, also you need to state your framework version or any other environment information that might seem pertinent  (both in the actual question)

Comment: FYI regarding formatted text vs images of text: This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.